# Vue 3 audio player

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js

I have been working on an **audio player** with Vue 3 and the Napster API.

```js
const musicApp = {
  data() {
    return {
      player: new Audio(),
      trackCount: 0,
      tracks: [],
      muted: false,
      autoAdvance: true,
      isPlaying: false,
      currentTime: 0
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async getTracks() {
      try {
        const response = await axios
          .get(
            "https://api.napster.com/v2.1/tracks/top?apikey=ZTk2YjY4MjMtMDAzYy00MTg4LWE2MjYtZDIzNjJmMmM0YTdm"
          )
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
        this.tracks = response;
        this.tracks = response.data.tracks;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
    nextTrack() {
      if (this.trackCount < this.tracks.length - 1) {
        this.trackCount++;
        this.setPlayerSource();
        this.playPause();
      }
    },
    prevTrack() {
      if (this.trackCount >= 1) {
        this.trackCount--;
        this.setPlayerSource();
        this.playPause();
      }
    },
    setPlayerSource() {
      this.player.src = this.tracks[this.trackCount].previewURL;
    },
    playPause() {
      if (this.player.paused) {
        this.isPlaying = true;
        this.player.play();
      } else {
        this.isPlaying = false;
        this.player.pause();
      }
    },
    skipProgress(e) {
      let barWidth = e.target.clientWidth;
      let rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
      let clickPositionX = e.pageX - rect.left;
      this.player.currentTime =
        (clickPositionX / barWidth) * this.player.duration;
    },
    toggleMute() {
      this.player.muted = !this.player.muted;
      this.muted = this.player.muted;
    }
  },
  async created() {
    await this.getTracks();
    this.setPlayerSource();
    this.$refs.progressBar.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      this.skipProgress(e);
    });
    this.player.addEventListener("ended", () => {
      this.isPlaying = false;

      if (this.autoAdvance) {
        this.nextTrack();
      }
    });
    this.player.addEventListener("timeupdate", () => {
      this.currentTime = this.player.currentTime;
    });
  },
  computed: {
    trackProgress() {
      return (this.currentTime / this.player.duration) * 100;
    }
  }
};

Vue.createApp(musicApp).mount("#audioPlayer");
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.player-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #2998ff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(62deg, #2998ff 0%, #5966eb 100%);
}

#audioPlayer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #00ca81;
  background-image: linear-gradient(160deg, #00ca81 0%, #ffffff 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 0.125rem 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.volume {
  color: #ff0057;
  opacity: 0.9;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.album {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.album-items {
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.cover {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 12px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: url("https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/710/955/png-transparent-vinyl-record-artwork-phonograph-record-compact-disc-lp-record-disc-jockey-symbol-miscellaneous-classical-music-sound.png") center top transparent;
  background-size: cover;
}

.cover.spinning {
  webkit-animation: spin 6s linear infinite;
  /* Safari */
  animation: spin 6s linear infinite;
}

.info {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  color: #000;
  opacity: 0.85;
}

.info h1 {
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.info h2 {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 3px 0 0 0;
}

.to-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.progress-bar {
  background-color: #ff0057;
  opacity: 0.9;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.progress-bar span {
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

.controls {
  width: 150px;
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.controls .navigate {
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 7px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
  width: 33px;
  height: 33px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #ff0057;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0.9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.controls .navigate.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #606060;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.controls .navigate.navigate-play {
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
}

.navigate-play .fa-play {
  margin-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.22.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="player-container">
  <div id="audioPlayer">
    <span class="volume" @click="toggleMute">
      <i v-show="!muted" class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
      <i v-show="muted" class="fa fa-volume-off"></i>
    </span>
    <div class="album">
      <div class="album-items">
        <div class="cover" :class="{'spinning' : isPlaying}"></div>
        <div class="info">
          <h1>{{tracks[trackCount].name}}</h1>
          <h2>{{tracks[trackCount].artistName}}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="to-bottom">
      <div class="progress-bar" ref="progressBar">
        <span :style="{ width: trackProgress + '%' }"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="controls">
        <div class="navigate navigate-prev" :class="{'disabled' : trackCount == 0}" @click="prevTrack">
          <i class="fa fa-step-backward"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="navigate navigate-play" @click="playPause">
          <i v-show="!isPlaying" class="fa fa-play"></i>
          <i v-show="isPlaying" class="fa fa-pause"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="navigate navigate-next" :class="{'disabled' : trackCount == tracks.length - 1}" @click="nextTrack">
          <i class="fa fa-step-forward"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Concerns

1. Is the code DRY enough?
2. Is the code far from sticking o best practices?
3. Is the app missing importan fetures in your oppinon?
4. What about the app's aesthetics?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, just want to say great job in creating your audio player! (I think I may have commented on one of the earlier issues you posted).

Secondly there is nothing "wrong" with your code but of course there are things that could be improved and even my suggestions may not be perfect, or could be improved upon still.

What I would say though is the following:

- The propery `trackCount` would lead most people to believe that it refers to the total number of tracks. Looking more closely at your code `trackIndex` or even `currentTrackIndex` would be clearer semantically, and immediately understood by someone reading for the first time. Do not underestimate the importance of naming your variables, properties and functions clearly!
- I have concerns about using `player: new Audio()` in the component's `data` as Vue will try and make this HTML audio element 'reactive' which is not necessary and a waste of resources setting up watchers etc. I would instead do one of the following:

  - Add a `player` property before `data`. This creates a static property which can be accessed in the script via `this.$options.player`.
  - At the top of your `created` method do `this.player = new Audio();`

  The advantage to the first option generally is that you can access the properties of `$options` in the template, although this probably won't affect your component.
- You have two repeated lines in your next/prev track methods. I would do a couple of things:

  - setup a computed property (which you can also use in the template!):

    ```
    computed: {
      currentTrack() {
        return this.tracks[this.trackIndex]
      }
    }
    ```
  - watch `trackIndex`:

    ```
    watch: {
      trackIndex(newTrackIndex, oldTrackIndex) {
        this.player.src = this.currentTrack.previewURL
      }
    }
    ```

I hope these suggestions help! :)

Comment: I kinda failed at making it beautiful. If only I would have a gorgeous interface to script.

Answer (score 6):

in the method `getTracks()`:

```js
this.tracks =response; 
this.tracks=response.data.tracks;
```

No need to set `this.tracks` twice, you can just go ahead and set `this.tracks =response.data.tracks`, avoiding the need to repeat yourself somehow.